# create triangle numbers pattern javascript and verticaly snake number pattern square

Tags: javascript, for-loop, numbers

i want create triangle number pattern

```js
let segitigaPola3 = num => {
  let hasil = ''
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      hasil += `${i} `
    }
    
    hasil += ` \n`
  }
  return hasil
}

console.log(segitigaPola3(5))
console.log()
console.log()
```

currently output is :

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

what i want is something like
for triangle :

```
1
2 3
4 5 4
3 2 1 2
3 4 5 4 3
```

and for square like :

```
1 10 11 20 21
2 9  12 19 22
3 8  13 18 23
4 7  14 17 24
5 6  15 16 25
```

how can i achieve like this?
thanks for any advice :)

Comment: what is the logic behind the square? do you have any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the triangle, this pattern have 4 conditions:

1. When the number is increasing:

   - If the current number is same as `num` ==> It's time to turn the flow to decreasing
   - Otherwise, keep it as it is.
2. When the number is decreasing:

   - If the current number reaches 1 ==> It's time to turn the flow to increasing
   - Otherwise, keep it as it is.

In this code below, I use `now` and `before` to track whether the current process/flow is increasing or decreasing, and then check if the current number reaches the turning point (1 or the `num` variable).

```js
let segitigaPola3 = num => {
  let hasil = ''
  
  let now = 1; // Set arbitrary counter
  let before = 0;
  
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      hasil += `${now} `;
      console.log(now, before, num);
      if (now > before) { // Check if the flow is increasing
        if (now !== num) { // Check for the turning point (num)
          now++;
          before++;
        } else {
          now--;
          before++;
        }
      } else {
        if (now > 1) { // Check if the current still not reached the turning point
          now--;
          before--;
        } else {  // When the current reaches the turning point
          now++;
          before--;
        }
      }
    }
    
    hasil += ` \n`
  }
  return hasil
}

console.log(segitigaPola3(5));
```

For the square, there are 2 conditions for the column-based elements:

1. For the odd columns, it's always increasing as from the upper row to bottom rows. Here's a highlight to see the pattern:

```
Row no. | i ( = Col no.) | j
------------------------------
 1      | 1              | 1
 5      | 1              | 5
------------------------------
 1      | 3              | 11
 5      | 3              | 15
```

This always starts from `(i-1)*num + 1` and always increases until ends up at `(i*num)` and we use `j` to fill the elements.

2. For the even columns, it's the reverse. Highlight to see the pattern:

```
Row no. | i ( = Col no.) | j
------------------------------
 1      | 2              | 10
 2      | 2              | 9
------------------------------
 1      | 4              | 20
 2      | 4              | 19
```

Based on the pattern above, this always starts from `i*num` and always increases until ends up at `(i-1)*num + 1` and we use `j` to fill the elements.

```js
function squareMaker(num) {
  let result = '';
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    let temp = [];
    
    // Generating the odd column elements
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
      for (let j = (i-1)*num + 1; j <= i*num; j++) { 
        temp.push(j);
      }
    } 
    
    // Generating the even column elements
    else {
      for (let j = i*num; j > (i-1)*num ; j--) {
        temp.push(j);
      }    
    }
    arr.push(temp);
  }
  
  // Generating the result string.
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < num; j++) {
      result += `${arr[j][i]} `;
    }
    result += '\n';
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(squareMaker(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

For a triangle pattern u can use @depperm's function. The vertical square snake pattern is a bit trickier:

```js
function triangle(count) {
  var result = "";
  var x = 1;
  var add = true;
  for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      result += x + " ";
      add ? x += 1 : x -= 1;
      if(x === count || (x === 1 && !add)) add =! add;
    }
    
    result += " \n";
  }
  return result;
}


function square(count) {
    var result = "";
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            var row = [0];
            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                var num = (j + 1) % 2 == 0 ? (j + 1) * count : row[j] + 1; 
                row.push(num);
            }
            row.shift();
        } else {
            var row = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                var num = (j + 1) % 2 == 0 ? (rows[i - 1][j] - 1) : (rows[i - 1][j] + 1);
                row.push(num);
            }
        }
        rows.push(row); 
        result += row.join(" ") + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(triangle(5));
console.log(square(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

For the triangle, I'd create a separate variable for the output number (`x`) and a flag for if it should add or subtract.

```js
let segitigaPola3 = num => {
  let hasil = ''
  let x=1;
  let add=true;
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      hasil += `${x} `
      add?x+=1:x-=1;
      if(x===num || (x===1 && !add)) add=!add
    }
    
    hasil += ` \n`
  }
  return hasil
}

console.log(segitigaPola3(5))
```